# How to find the mean and the variance in assembly from an unsigned integer into a floating-point number/decimal

Tags: assembly, mean, variance, unsigned-integer, floating-point-conversion

Here is the code that I have below:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto, dwExitCode:dword


PWORD TYPEDEF PTR WORD


.data

RAW WORD 10, 12 , 8, 17, 9, 22, 18, 11, 23, 7, 30, 22, 19, 60, 71
ptr1 PWORD RAW
TEXT1 BYTE "Mean: ", 0
TEXT2 BYTE "Variance: ", 0





TOTAL WORD LENGTHOF RAW
SUM DWORD 0
MEAN DWORD 0
VARSUM DWORD 0





.code
main proc
    mov eax, 0
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF RAW 
    mov esi, OFFSET RAW
    

    SumLoop:
        mov esi,ptr1
        add eax, [esi]
        add esi, TYPE RAW
        loop SumLoop
    
    ; Taking the avg of the numbers
    mov SUM, eax
    cdq
    mov ebx, 15
    div ebx
    mov MEAN, eax
    

    
    





    
    
    

    


    

    invoke ExitProcess, 0

main endp
end main
```

The question I have is that I am trying to get the mean and the variance from an unsigned integer into a floating-point number/decimal(Format: Mean:XX and Variance:YY). I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do this.

Comment: Which floating point unit would you like to use?  X87 or SSE?

Answer (score 0):

Integer division will give you an integer quotient and integer remainder.

If you want a mean with decimal places, convert the sum and count to floating point *before* dividing — then use floating point division to get a floating point answer.

For example, in C:

```
float answer = (float) sum / (float) 15;
```

A compiler can show you the [instructions to use](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:4),source:%27//+Type+your+code+here,+or+load+an+example.%0Aint+square(int+sum,+int+count)+%7B%0A++++return+(float)+sum+/+(float)+count%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g112,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-m32+-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).  (You may have to pick a different compiler and/or compiler options for your environment.)